# How to make generated code from creative commons licence pass validation

Tags: html, validation

I'm trying to make my site pass a few different validators. The [wc3](http://validator.w3.org/) is passing all of the html I've written, but throwing errors for the code generated by the [CC licencing website](http://creativecommons.org/choose/).

I found [this explanation from 2011](http://taske.org/invalid-xhtml-with-the-creative-commons-license-markup/) but it requires setting things for the whole page.

Is there a way to say that a particular div uses their kind of xml or something along those lines?

For some context, Here's the generated code:

```
<a rel="license" href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/">
   <img alt="Creative Commons License" style="border-width:0; float: left;" src="https://i.creativecommons.org/l/by-sa/4.0/88x31.png" />
</a>
<span xmlns:dct="http://purl.org/dc/terms/" href="http://purl.org/dc/dcmitype/InteractiveResource" property="dct:title" rel="dct:type">Posted Notes
</span> by 
<span xmlns:cc="http://creativecommons.org/ns#" property="cc:attributionName">Ben Doherty &amp; Irina Belova
</span> is licensed under a 
<a rel="license" href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/">Creative Commons Attribution-ShareAlike 4.0 International License</a>.
```

which renders as:[image: a screenshot of the cc licence]

And here's [the website on it's own](http://postednot.es) and [plugged into a validator](http://goo.gl/4JN7Z4).

**Options:**

- So far I've thought of just manually stripping the offending markup out, but it was put in there for a reason (Surely!) so I'm hesitant to do that.
- The other option is to set the doctype as suggested in the link above, but I don't really know enough about pre-html5 doctypes to understand the suggestions.

To reiterate the question: How do I get my page to pass validation? (Or, should I just not care?)

Comment: What's the goal behind having your markup pass HTML validation? Is your site having some issues or are you just trying to pass the validation just for the sake of it?

Comment: Mainly just for the sake of it. But if it turns out to be useful it might save me from writing a load of tests.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend that you do it just for the sake it (unless this is a learning exercise). This is a good post on HTML validation that I think you might find useful: http://blog.codinghorror.com/html-validation-does-it-matter/